# Basis of Vector Space with Non-Standard Definition of Addition and Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Consider the vector space $V = \mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^+ \times\mathbb R^+$, where $\mathbb R^+$ is the set of all positive real numbers with addition and scalar multiplication defined by

$(x_1, y_1, z_1) \oplus (x_2, y_2, z_2) = (x_1x_2, y_1y_2, z_1z_2)$

$\alpha(x, y, z) = (x^\alpha, y^\alpha, z^\alpha), \alpha\in\mathbb R$

Find the dimension of the vector space $V$ and find a basis of $V$ which contains the element $(e, e, 1)$

I know it has something to do with exponential or logarithmic function but can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, $V\to\mathbb R^3$ given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto (\log x,\log y,\log z)$ is an isomorphism. It sends $(e,e,1)$ to $(1,1,0)$, so construct a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ containing $(1,1,0)$ and send it back through the inverse isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Prove $V $ is $3$ dimensional,  with basis  $\{(e,e,1),(e,1,e),(1,e,e)\}$.  Thus it's isomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$.